# Crawling a web page for image urls

Tags: python, image, web-crawler

The following is a piece of code in python for crawling through a webpage and printing out the urls of the images:

```
import urllib, re

source = urllib.urlopen('http://www.gardensafari.net/english/squirrels.htm').read()

## every image name is an abbreviation composed by capital letters, so...
m = re.findall('.*?\\.(?i)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|tif|tiff)', source)

for link in re.findall('.*?\\.(?i)(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|tif|tiff)', source):
    print link
```

However, it only prints the extensions:

```
jpg
jpg
jpg
gif
jpg
gif
jpg
jpg
jpg
jpg...
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the input data is HTML, I would use an *HTML parser* instead.

Here is the working example involving [`BeautifulSoup` parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen('http://www.gardensafari.net/english/squirrels.htm'))

for img in soup.find_all("img", src=True):
    print(img["src"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Follow up question - What if the input data is not html? For instance, when use the above script and the url is - `https://www.airbnb.com/` it does not give out any results. What can be done then?

Comment: @codepi well, airbnb site is generally quite dynamic, you might explore the API they provide. Thanks.